# ReferenceError when setting a Global variable in Postman

Tags: postman

I get an error when trying to extract a value from a JSON response body in Postman.

> ReferenceError: teste is not defined

This is what I have tried:

```
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
  pm.globals.set("access_token",jsonData.access_token)

  ** pm.globals.set("x-teste-msg-sign",jsonData.x-teste-msg-sign)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more than likely to be this, judging by the way you're extracting the `access_token`

```
  pm.globals.set("x-teste-msg-sign", jsonData["x-teste-msg-sign"])
```

As the `key` contains the `-` character, you would need to use bracket notion rather than dot notion to access the value.

Here's an example:

```
let jsonData = {
  "x-teste-msg-sign": 12345
}

console.log(jsonData.x-teste-msg-sign) // This would cause a script error
console.log(jsonData["x-teste-msg-sign"]) // This would set the value to the variable
```

Comment: It worked .Thank very much .

it was very difficult to find, I searched a lot

Comment: It's a common problem for people accessing different part of a JSON response. Could you accept this as the answer please 